# PHP inside echo in a function?

Tags: php, function, echo

I have this part of the code of a plugin, which continues and has much php before it, fluidly without the ?> till the end of all the code.

```
function fivu_thumbnail_meta_box_html() {
echo '<label for="featured_image_url">';
_e("URL of featured image", 'fivu_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="featured_image_url" name="featured_image_url" value=""    size="30" />'; 
}
```

What i need is to change the input value="" (5th line) to this:

```
value="<?php get_post_custom_values("Poster"); ?>"
```

But as i am inside of an echo, the php is not interpreted as php but as normal text.
¿What can i do to make the php inside of the echo not to be interpeted as normal text?

EDIT: Ok, i am using

```
echo '<input type="text" id="featured_image_url" name="featured_image_url" value="' .    get_post_custom_values("Poster") . '"    size="30" />';
```

But i forgot, lol, i need to echo the value. So how do i add: echo $values[0]; ?

Comment: [*String concatenation*, man, *string concatenation*.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like HTML in echo.

So Try :-

```
function fivu_thumbnail_meta_box_html() {
?>
<label for="featured_image_url">
<?php
_e("URL of featured image", 'fivu_textdomain' );
?>
</label>
<input type="text" id="featured_image_url" name="featured_image_url" value="<?php echo get_post_custom_values("Poster"); ?>"  size="30" />
<?php 
}
```

Comment: When i wanted to add the echo it was like this: <?php $values = get_post_custom_values("Poster"); echo $values[0]; ?>, so i replaced the code and use this method. Aside of being cleaner and clearer, it is more useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `<?php` again as you're already inside a PHP control. You simply need to concatenate your string with the `get_post_custom_values` function's return value, like so:

```
echo '<input ... value="'.get_post_custom_values("Poster").'" ... />';
```

So we have string + function's return value + string, three components which together contribute to the output of the input field HTML.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, meant to edit my own answer, no idea what happened (using Android SO app)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [string concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), `.`:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="featured_image_url" name="featured_image_url" value="' . get_post_custom_values("Poster") . '"    size="30" />';
```